# subprocess.getoutput with sed shell command in Python 3 returns null string

Tags: bash, python-3.x, sed, subprocess

I use the following command in sh or bash to obtain the resolution of a movie file:

```
/opt/local/bin/ffmpeg -i TEST.mp4 2>&1 | sed -n "s/.*, \(.*\) \[.*/\1/p"
```

...and it returns a string like “640x480” for the input file resolution. Great.

Converting this over to a Python 3.4 script, I can’t seem to get it to work:

```
import subprocess
stdoutstr = subprocess.getoutput('/opt/local/bin/ffmpeg -i /Users/alexis/TEST.mp4 2>&1 | /usr/bin/sed -n "s/.*, \(.*\) \[.*/\1/p"')
print("stdoutstr:” + stdoutstr.split()[0])
```

The Python 3 code above returns a null string. How can I get this to work?

Comment: Please next time clarify that you **are** in fact using Python 3. I was initially confused by your question because ``commands.getoutput()`` did exist for a time and was deprecated. I didn't notice that ``subprocess.getoutput()`` now exists in Python 3+ (*it doesn't in Python 2.7*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you used [subprocess.check_output](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) it will throw an exception if the command fails. This would give you an idea of what is going wrong.

But the real issue is that you must specify `shell=True` to allow the shell to interpret your redirections. Otherwise the executed command will contain the literal metacharacters like `|` and space which you probably don't want.

Without `shell=True`, it is just like if you put single quotes around the *entire* command at the shell prompt. That will obviously fail with a command not found error.

This should work for you:

```
stdoutstr = subprocess.check_output(
    """/opt/local/bin/ffmpeg -i /Users/alexis/TEST.mp4 2>&1 | /usr/bin/sed -n 's/.*, \(.*\) \[.*/\\1/p'""",
    shell=True, universal_newlines=True)
```

I'll warn you that on my machine `ffmpeg` is not located in `/opt/local/bin` and `sed` is not located in `/usr/bin/sed`. On my machine, `ffmpeg` is in `/usr/bin` and `sed` is in `/bin/sed`, so I had to tweak the command slightly to put it back in your original example. Alternatively, if these locations are already in your PATH, you could just remove them entirely:

```
stdoutstr = subprocess.check_output(
    """ffmpeg -i /Users/alexis/TEST.mp4 2>&1 | sed -n 's/.*, \(.*\) \[.*/\\1/p'""",
    shell=True, universal_newlines=True)
```

Comment: When I add shell=True it complains about the syntax:

    stdoutstr = subprocess.getoutput('/opt/local/bin/ffmpeg -i /Users/alexis/TEST.mp4 2>&1 | /usr/bin/sed -n "s/.*, \(.*\) \[.*/\1/p"',shell=True)
TypeError: getoutput() got an unexpected keyword argument 'shell'

And when I don’t use shell=True it complains about the argument itself:

    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/opt/local/bin/ffmpeg -i /Users/alexis/TEST.mp4 2>&1 | /usr/bin/sed -n "s/.*, \\(.*\\) \\[.*/\x01/p"'

So I don’t really know how to proceed with this.

Comment: And if I use Popen('...', stdout=PIPE, shell=True) the output (using .communicate()[0]) is b'\x01\n' instead of 640x480.

Comment: I updated my answer with a full example. I tested this locally on my machine for a random mp4 file that I had laying around.

Comment: Awesome! Yes! That works to obtain the resolution string. Now if I replace the sed string with: sed -n 's/.*, \(.*\) fp.*/\\1/p' it should return the framerate of the movie file (in frames/sec). However, it returns null, so I’m puzzled…

Comment: You need to backslash escape the parenthesis. They are metacharacters to `sed`.

Comment: Indeed! This all works now. The proper incantation for FPS is: "\"\"ffmpeg -i " + moviespec + " 2>&1 | sed -n 's/.*, \(.*\) fp.*/\\1/p'\"\""  Thanks so much for all your help!!!